# Nginx isn't redirecting right

Tags: nginx, web-server, php-fpm

I'm starting with Nginx and have a lot of problems since things change from Apache to Nginx. Right now I have a application developed in Symfony1.4 which don't work since I get a `404 Not Found` error. This are the logs for error:

```
 2014/02/07 21:28:49 [error] 2091#0: *22 open()
 "/var/www/html/apps/monitor/web/index.php/login" failed (20: Not a
 directory), client: 192.168.3.1, server: devserver, request: "POST
 /apps/monitor/web/index.php/login HTTP/1.1", host: "devserver",
 referrer: "http://devserver/apps/monitor/web/" 2014/02/07 21:29:11
 [error] 2091#0: *22 open() "/var/www/html/apps/monitor/web/login"
 failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.3.1, server:
 devserver, request: "GET /apps/monitor/web/login HTTP/1.1", host:
 "devserver"
```

And this is the content of my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  devserver;
    root   /var/www/html;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        index  index.php;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

**Added `try_files` directive**

I've added `try_files` as follow but doesn't fix the issue I'm having:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

**EDIT2: Try another way, get 500 server error**

I've tried another alternative changing to this:

index  index.php app.php index.html index.htm;

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

location @rewrite {
   rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index app.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

But logs said this:

```
2014/02/07 22:06:11 [error] 2905#0: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/apps/monitor/web/index.php/login", client: 192.168.3.1, server: devserver, request: "GET /apps/monitor/web/index.php/login HTTP/1.1", host: "devserver"
```

Comment: Where is your `try_files`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton what you mean with `try_files`?